# React CSS Modules, Is not working. Some Idea?

Tags: reactjs, sass, webpack

I install all the dependences:

```
    "devDependencies": {
      "css-loader": "^0.26.4",
      "sass-loader": "^6.0.3",
      "style-loader": "^0.13.2
    }
```

The bundle detect my import correctly:

```
import styles from './styles.scss';
```

and I configure my webpack config:

```
module : {
    loaders : [
        {
            test: /\.(sass|scss)$/,
            use: ['style-loader', 'css-loader', 'sass-loader']
        },
        {
            test : /\.jsx?/,
            include : APP_DIR,
            loader : 'babel-loader'
        }
    ]
}
```

But in the final render doesn't appear the classes.
Some idea? Thank you!!!

Comment: what kind of an error you seeing?

Comment: @KornholioBeavis That's the problem. I can't see any error. The bundle is OK, but in the final render, the classes doesn't appear in the html tag.

Comment: does it give you a value other than undefined if you debug the object?

Comment: have you actually included react-css-modules in you project?

Comment: Theres a great example for a simple setup https://github.com/css-modules/webpack-demo

Comment: @KornholioBeavis Thank you so much for your help. How can I include the react-css-modules. There is not a npm module for that or I can't found it.

Comment: Please follow the example for clearer implementation.

Comment: you need to import css inside the top root component the generated css using webpack.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I know that's not perfect solution, but working:
in my project css are bundled in one bundle.css file and my settings are:

1.In components i got:
   `import "./User.css";`

2.In webpack config:
`var ExtractTextPlugin = require('extract-text-webpack-plugin');`

3.And then in webpack config module section:

```
module: {
    loaders: [
        { test: /\.tsx?$/, loader: "awesome-typescript-loader" },
        { test: /\.js$/, loader: "source-map-loader", enforce: "pre" },
        {
            test: /\.css$/,
            loader: ExtractTextPlugin.extract({
                fallback: 'style-loader',
                use: "css-loader",
            })
        }
    ]
},
plugins: [
new ExtractTextPlugin('../css/[name].css')
]
```

Answer (score 0):

Your jsx test value is wrong, isn't it? Has to be

```
{
    test : /\.jsx$/,
    include : APP_DIR,
    loader : 'babel-loader'
}
```